# how can I avoid the circular reference in vs.net?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I am using an asp.net 3.5 web solution with js which contains 2 projects ProjectA and ProjectB. ProjectA has a reference to ProjectB.  Now I would like to use a class that sits in ProjectA from somewhere in ProjectB? Vs.net wont let me refer to ProjectA now because of a circular reference? Do I have to refactor of is there a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move common code to Project C and add reference to it from Projects A & B.

Or merge both projects into one.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this type of error before because I was Declaring a variable **Globally** inside a class referencing ProjectA. I resolve it by instead of declaring variable Globally, I declared it inside a Sub/Function

Project B

```
Public Sub ReferenceProjectA()
   Dim objProjectA As New ProjectA
   objProjectA.ProjectAFunction("")

End Sub
```